# Finding $c$ such that the average distance from $y(x)=c$ to the origin is $d$ - is there an easier way than mine?

Tags: geometry, definite-integrals, average

I would like to find $c$ such that the average distance from points on the graph $y(x)=c$ to the origin is $d$, when $x\in[0,x_f]$, as the figure illustrates:

[image]

I think my solution is correct, however I had to use a probability distribution for $x$ (see below), but I suspect this wouldn't be necessary for a geometry problem.

> Is there a simpler, more geometrically intuitive way of solving this problem?

---

**My solution:**

The average is given as

$$\langle f(x) \rangle=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)p(x)dx$$ 
and here

\begin{align}
f(x)&=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \\ 
x_f&=c\tan \gamma_f \\
p(x)&=\cases{\frac{1}{x_f} \quad 0\leq x  <x_f \\ 0 \quad \;\; \text{otherwise}}
\end{align}
Making the substitution $x\rightarrow \gamma'$, where $x=c \tan \gamma'$, the average distance becomes
\begin{align}
d&=\int_0^{x_f}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x_f}dx \\
&=\frac{c}{\tan \gamma_f}\int_0^{\gamma_f} \sec^3 \gamma' d\gamma'
\end{align}

Dropping the $f$ in $\gamma_f$, this evaluates to

\begin{align}
d&=\frac{c}{2}\left(\sec \gamma +\cot \gamma \ln \left(1+\frac{2}{\cot \gamma/2 -1} \right) \right) \Rightarrow \\
c&=\frac{2d}{\sec \gamma +\cot \gamma \ln \left(1+\frac{2}{\cot \gamma/2 -1} \right)}
\end{align}

Here it is plotted:

[image]

Comment: Well, the probability distribution you had to "conjure" up is the uniform distribution with respect to arc length - which seems to be the only correct way of interpreting the word "average" ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen "Conjure" is perhaps the wrong word - I, of course, didn't pull the distribution out of thin air. It is just that I didn't expect to have to use a PDF in this type of problem.

Comment: I consider the combination of infinite integral and the piecewise constant probability density function a bit verbose. You can (and in a later step actually do) express this more easily as an integral over a finite range, with the uniform distribution implied by the parametrization. So you don't *have* to use a PDF. Anyway, what actually is your input? Because if $x_f$ is given, then expressing things in terms of $\gamma_f$ is not the whole solution, since $\gamma_f$ depends on the combination of $x_f$ and $c$. If $\gamma_f$ is given, please say so.

Comment: @MvG $\gamma_f$ is the given :) What would be the justification of skipping the step where I insert the expression for the PDF?

Comment: Just knowing that for uniform distribution, you integrate over the whole domain and divide by the measure of the domain. Sure, that's something you could, and in some setups should, derive from the PDF. But on a more basic level, it's probably something many people will learn even before they hear about PDFs in the first place. Probably by deriving it from situations with finite domains of discrete values, where they compute the average by summing then dividing by the number of cases.